# AS3: GC by reference counting - Should I set textField.defaultTextFormat = null?

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, garbage-collection

I'm trying to be very careful about removing references from objects when I am done with them so they will be eligible for the faster Reference Counting method of Garbage Collection. I have a class that creates a TextField and applies a TextFormat to it. The TextFormat uses a local variable, so I know I don't have to worry about nulling it since it will go out of scope, but should I set the TextField's defaultTextFormat property to null when I'm done? After it goes out of scope, the TextFormat is still applied to the TextField, so I suppose that might still be considered a reference, even though it has no variable name.

Also, is there an easy way to see how many references an object has so I can check to see if it's 0?

Comment: When you create a TextField, it has automatically a TextFormat object assigned (you should be able to verify it by simply tracing textfield.defaultTextFormat right after instantiating a textfield). You cannot just set it to null.

Comment: I don't think there is any exposed way to get the reference count of an object in AS3, though it would certainly be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain `TextFormats` are copied when you assign them, meaning they are not references to the original objects.

This would mean there would not be any impact on garbage collection whether you set it to `null` or not (which subsequently `null` is not a valid value for `defaultTextFormat`) since the TextField doesn't hold a reference to the passed `TextFormat` object.

Example:

```
var txt:TextField = new TextField();

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

txt.defaultTextFormat = tf;

tf.color = 0xFF0000;
txt.text = txt.text; //color will stay the same (not red) since it doesn't actually reference the original object

txt.defaultTextFormat = tf; //now it will change color since we reapplied it (it made a new copy of the text format object).
txt.text = txt.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do : `text_field.defaultTextFormat = null`, you will get a `TypeError` error. Also, I think that Flash assign always a default `TextFormat` to a text field, so the best manner is to use it after set the text format as null, like this :

```
var text_field:TextField = new TextField()
    text_field.text = 'hello world !'
    addChild(text_field)

var default_fmt:TextFormat = text_field.getTextFormat()
var new_fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat()
    new_fmt.color = 0xff9900

// we start by assigning the new text format to our text field to get an orange text
text_field.defaultTextFormat = new_fmt
text_field.text = text_field.text   

// then we can free our new text format and assign the default text format to our text field
new_fmt = null
text_field.defaultTextFormat = default_fmt
text_field.text = text_field.text
```

For your second part of question, about object references, I think that you are speaking about object instances, if yes, you can try this function :

```
function get_instances_count(container:DisplayObjectContainer, type:Class):int {
    var count:int = 0
    for(var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++){
        var obj = container.getChildAt(i)
        if(obj is type){
            count++
        }
    }
    return count;
}
// to use it
trace(get_instances_count(stage, red_button))
```

Comment: OP was asking about references to an instance, not how many instances. As in, how many objects in the application still hold reference to a specific instance?